# Get data from another controller from a view .net application

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, .net-framework-version, data-access

In normal set up we have:

```
Controllers/MyController.cs

Views/MyController/Index.cshtml
```

If I instantiate a model called `MyModel` in `Index()` of `MyController` then in my `Index.cshtml` view
if I simply type `@model <AppName>.Model.MyModel`, the visual studio knows to get data from `Index()` of `MyController.cs` class. 
My question is how to tell my view to get data from some other Controller class. The view does not have any explicit reference to the controller (something like `@model <AppName>.Model.MyModel` = [Get Data from MyController])
I created a controller (has no view) called `DataAccessController.cs`. All-access to data from any view must route through this Controller.

Comment: You may be looking to add a Partial View, or create a relationship between Class A and Class B, so that, for example, Class A has an instance of Class B.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Partial Views.

Comment: I think you are looking for  RedirectToAction("Methodname", "Controllername");